# syntax error--SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I am trying to print a list of accounts that are at 2 locations. Here's what I've put in:

```
SELECT cust_id, account_id, product_cd 
from account 
SELECT name 
from branch 
where name = 'So. NH Branch' or name = 'Woburn Branch';
```

When I do the query I get this message: Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT name 
from branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use JOIN. You could try

```
SELECT cust_id, account_id, product_cd, name
FROM account, branch
WHERE name = 'So. NH Branch' or name = 'Woburn Branch';
```

But it depends on your schema as to whether it'll work

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to join the tables

```
SELECT  cust_id, account_id, product_cd 
from    account
        INNER JOIN branch 
            ON account.colName = branch.colName -- the relationship between
                                                -- the two tables
where   name IN ('So. NH Branch',  'Woburn Branch');
```

but another interpretation of the query is that you want to execute multiple queries. When doing that each statement should be separated by a `semi-colon`

```
SELECT cust_id, account_id, product_cd 
from   account;

SELECT name 
from   branch 
where  name IN ('So. NH Branch',  'Woburn Branch');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two SQL statements here, they need to be split up, or joined into a single statement:

```
SELECT cust_id, account_id, product_cd 
from account;

SELECT name 
from branch 
where name = 'So. NH Branch' or name = 'Woburn Branch';
```

The SQL interpreter is looking for a `;` before the second `SELECT` is found.